# NotificationBuilder or NotificationCompat.Builder does not show actions

Tags: android

Playing with this for three hours and can't figure what's wrong.

```
private static Notification buildNotification(Context context) {
    NotificationCompat.Builder b = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
    b.setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(
            context, 0, new Intent(context,  MyActivity.class),
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
    b.setTicker(context.getString(R.string.update_notification_title));
    b.setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.update_notification_title));
    b.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.icon));
    b.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon);
    b.setOngoing(true);
    b.setAutoCancel(false);
    b.setProgress(100, 0, true);

    Intent cancel = new Intent(context,  Updater.class);
    cancel.putExtra(EXTRA_CANCEL, true);
    b.addAction(
            R.drawable.discard_holo_dark,
            context.getString(R.string.ui_cancel),
            PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, cancel, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
    return b.build();
}
```

I tried the default NotificationBuilder on JellyBean as well.
Also been trying to change PendingIntent to getActivity and tried to replace icons and text as well. Tried to setOngoing(false), without progress and with autoCancel. Still no luck seings by buttons. Tried on four different devices.

Comment: Do any of those devices run Android 4.1 or higher?

Comment: Yes, tried on Galaxy S3 (stock 4.1.1), HTC One V (CM10 custom). Though the compat builder should show actions on non-JB devices (tried on Nexus One and Galaxy Tab - no actions too).
I am sure I am using the latest lib.

Comment: You might compare what you are doing with this sample app, which definitely works: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Notifications/BigNotify

Comment: Thanks, but I can't pinpoint what am I doing wrong. I was staring at other code snippets and docs as well, but did not see anything wrong in my implementation. I'll try to set priority as high and see if it helps when I get my hands on.

Comment: First, run my app. If it works, then slowly morph my code to work like yours, until it breaks, to determine where things are going wrong. If my code does not work on your devices, then test your code on the emulator -- if it works, then the problem is with your devices, not your code.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a try and let you know.

Comment: Nope, your code does not show actions on my devices.

Comment: It should look like the top `Notification` in this image: http://misc.commonsware.com/notify7.png If that is not what you are seeing, and you did not modify my project, then something may be up with your devices. Try your code on a 4.1 or 4.2 emulator.

Comment: Hmm, my code worked on Emulator 4.1. But does not show buttons on Galaxy S3 4.1.1. Seems it's a phone problem.
And also, NotificationCompat.Builder actions are now shown in Android < 4.1. Thanks for suggesting the experiment!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

NotificationCompat.Builder will not show Actions on Android < 4.1

On some devices, if there are multiple notifications, the notification with actions appear collapsed. Swiping down on the notification with two pointers gesture expands the actions.

Answer (score 2):

I have just tested that when debug mode is on and the Samsung Galaxy Note II (4.1.2) is connected to my PC throw USB (developing with Eclipse ADT), the notification action buttons are not shown (with .addAction). Instead, whether the device is not conected but with the debug mode activated, the action buttons are really shown. I don't know the reason.

An instesting app to test this that helped a lot to discard problems with my device, is ["Jelly Bean Notification Test"](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sloy.jbnotif) that is available on Google Play with the [source code](https://github.com/Sloy/Jelly-Bean-Notification-Test/) on GitHub. Thanks to its creator.

This app was also tested on a Samsung Galaxy SIII showing the notification action buttons. Remark that this device had debug mode off and was not connected to the PC for developing.

Comment: Also tested on a Asus TF300TG tablet with 4.1.1 using that app with  debug mode on and (in this case) also connected via USB to my Eclipse ADT. The notification action buttons are shown.

Answer (score 2):

I believe there are actually several answers, all true:

- Doctoror Drive: "On some devices, if there are multiple notifications, the notification with actions appear collapsed. Swiping down on the notification with two pointers gesture expands the actions."
- If you set the notification's priority to high it will always show the buttons and you don't have to swipe to expand (in your example above):

  `b.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH);
  //b.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH);//this if you're using Compat`
- Someone above said this may not work on tablets - I'm not sure if this is true but something to definitely consider and test

Comment: It helps me with device ZTE Nubia z5 mini

Answer (score 1):

I don't see where you are actually using this Notification. You must call [`NotificationManager#notify()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#notify%28int,%20android.app.Notification%29).

Comment: I did not provide this code, as it is not the part of notification build process. The notification, of course, appears, but with no actions. Just title, icon and indeterminate ProgressBar.

Answer (score 1):

I found that the buttons are not shown for tablets. Even with the sample code "Jelly Bean Notification Test", the behavior is the same. I tested on Samsung P3100 and Nexus7. While the same code works on most phones like LG P880. But not all. It's not shown on phones like Sony Xperia Z.

Comment: I've recently found that notifications have "hidden" expand feature on Samsumg Galaxy S2 - you need to swipe the notification vertically to expand the buttons. How stupid of Samsung.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that notifications will be in a collapsed state with actions hidden when there are many notifications in the notification window, they may be expanded when there are few or no other notifications present at least this is the behavior I have observed in Jelly bean 4.1.2